# Determining the joint density function -- what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function

Let $T_1$ be the time between a car accident and the claim reported to the insurance company. Let $T_2$ be the time between the report of the claim and payment of the claim. The joint density function of $T_1$ and $T_2$, $f(t_1, t_2)$,  is constant over the region $0<t_1, t_2<6, t_1+t_2<10$ and zero otherwise. Determine $f(t_1, t_2)$.

**My attempt**: Let $f(t_1, t_2) = k$. Then,
$$\int_0^6 \int_0^{10-y} k \; dx\; dy = \int_0^6 k(10-y) \; dy = 1 \implies k\left[60-\frac{35}{2}\right] = 1$$

which ultimately gives $k = \frac{1}{42}$, however, the correct answer is $k = \frac{1}{34}$. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Your integral is incorrect. Your limits correspond to the region $0 < t_1,t_2 < 10, t_1 + t_2 < 10$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann could you please explain how my integral is incorporating $6<t_1, t_2 <10$?

Comment: If $0<y<6$ and $0<x<10-y$ then one point in the region is $(7,2).$

Comment: @mfl I see. Would you recommend breaking down the area of interest into two separate double integrals?

Comment: Yes, I do recommend that. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cx%3C6%2C0%3Cy%3C6%2C+x%2By%3C10

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson I should have said $0 < t_1 < 10, 0 < t_2 < 6, t_1 + t_2 < 10$. In any case, I recommend simple geometry and subtraction rather than addition

Comment: @mfl That did the trick. But do you think we could have gotten to the correct solution by using some different bounds of integration (without dividing the area of interest into two separate areas)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method is that your integral is incorrect. Your limits correspond to the region $0 < t_1< 10, 0<t_2<6, t_1 + t_2 < 10$.

Here's an alternative approach. Let $R$ denote the region in question. First of all, note that
$$
\iint_R k\,dx\,dy = k\cdot \iint_R dx\,dy = 1,
$$
where $R$ denotes the region of interest. We can rearrange the above to find that
that $k = 1/A$, where $A = \iint_R 1\,dx\,dy$ is the area of $R$. To compute the area, subtract the area of a triangle from the area of a square. In particular, define
$$
R_1 = \{x,y : 0 < x < 6, 0 < y < 6\},\\
R_2 = \{x,y: 0 < x < 6, 0 < y < 6 \text{ and } x + y \geq 10\}.
$$
Verify that $R = R_1 \setminus R_2$, which is to say that $R$ contains the points of $R_1$ not included in $R_2$. $R_1$ is a square with area $6 \times 6 = 36$, and $R_2$ is a triangle with area $\frac 12 2 \times 2 = 2$. Thus, the area of $R$ is $36 - 2 = 34$.

Thus, we arrive at the correct answer $k = 1/A = 1/34$.

Comment: The alternative approach is much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 2):

*Blue line*: the area on which you should have integrated.

*Orange line*: the area on which you actually integrated.

[image]

Comment: Visualizations really help! :) +1